# MikroTik cAP ac - run as an access point without DHCP

Tags: wireless-networking, mikrotik-routeros

I'm trying to set up an MikroTik cAP ac as a bare Wifi-AP. There is already a (non-)MikroTik router serving DHCP so the MikroTik should only serve as an access-point in the same subnet.

I tried following those instructions but both solutions don't work as there's no WiFi-signal after the reboot.

How can i make this thing run as a simple WiFi-AP?

Answer (score 2):

This article explains exactly what i need: https://tehnoblog.org/mikrotik-router-how-to-convert-hap-or-hap-lite-into-ordinary-switch-or-wireless-access-point-bridge/

For future reference if the article is taken down:

**Desired topology:** [image]

**Steps:**

1. Reset device
2. Bridge > Ports: Add ether1 to bridge
3. IP > DHCP Server: delete defined one
4. IP > DHCP Client: delete defined one
5. Routing > BFD: disable defined all
6. reboot device

Comment: You can keep the DHCP client; it's useful for APs just as for other devices. As for "Routing > BFD" – that has no relation to the 'basic' routing functionality (you're already bypassing that when using the bridge); BFD configuration only matters when using Routing>OSPF or Routing>BGP, which are already disabled.

Comment: To enable access to the device despite the bridge? Wouldn't that be the DHCP server?

Comment: No. "DHCP server" gives out address leases to other devices (you want to disable this, as your ISP gateway already acts as the network's DHCP server), but "DHCP client" only takes an address lease for the AP _from_ the ISP gateway. But there's no important advantage over using a static IP for the AP, so it's up to you in the end. (I might have forgotten the default though – I guess the default is to run a DHCP client on ether1, so it should be at least changed to run on bridge1 instead.)